# Issue with CSS and JavaScript menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm coding a website for school. I have coded a side menu that has options that you click. And I've also coded some of those things that you click. My problem, is even though they exist, it says "filler.html does not exist." when I click. Even though they exist. So, here's my code. If you have any further questions, ask away.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.ABox {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgrey;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1%;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px !important;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <br>
  <a href="/StoryTime.html">The beginning of logic and rhetoric</a>
  <a href="/rhetoric.html">What is rhetoric?</a>
  <a href="/classics.html">What is classics?</a>
  <a href="/timeline.html" Timeline</a>
</div>

<div class="ABox">
  <h2>Classics and Rhetoric</h2>
</div>
<p style="background-color:black;color:lightgrey;width:200px;padding:1%;"></p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the leading "/". This means absolute directories, when you want relative.

```
<a href="StoryTime.html">The beginning of logic and rhetoric</a>
<a href="rhetoric.html">What is rhetoric?</a>
<a href="classics.html">What is classics?</a>
<a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

**From:**

```
<a href="/timeline.html" Timeline</a>
```

**To:**

```
<a href="/timeline.html"> Timeline</a>
```

Comment: All that did was delete them from my SideNav, and then I tried "/" on the outside of the quotations, and that gave me the same problem.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for all of your help. I don't know what I did, but I think it may have been an issue with the files. Thanks again!